# How does ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy work? What does queueBrowserPrefetch mean?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to use ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy but cannot quite understand how to use it.

I'm using queue, there are 3 params that I can define for PrefetchPolicy:

queuePrefetch, queueBrowserPrefetch, inputStreamPrefetch

Actually I don't get the meaning of queueBrowserPrefetch and inputStreamPrefetch so I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have seen the ActiveMQ page on [prefetch limits](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html).

- queueBrowserPrefetch sets the maximum number of messages sent to a
  [ActiveMQQueueBrowser](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.4.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQQueueBrowser.html) until acks are received.
- inputStreamPrefetch    sets the maximum number of messages sent
  through a [jms-stream](http://activemq.apache.org/jms-streams.html)    until acks are received

Both queue-browser and jms-stream are specialized consumers. You can read more about each one of them but if you are not using them it won't matter what you assign to their prefetch limits.

Comment: This helps. Now I understand both of them are specialized consumers.Interestingly they are documented in the ActiveMQ site or hard to find it. Anyway thanks a lot.